# XML Schema Generation based on class in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I need XML schema generation like below:

```
<Fields xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <Field dt:dt="string"></Field>
 <Field dt:dt="int" NULLABLE="1" READONLY="0"></Field>
</Fields>
```

I have class like this, with Element information

```
Class Person{
   public string name;

  [XmlElement(DataType = "int", Type = typeof(int), IsNullable=false)]
   public int id;
}
```

Comment: What language? Please, add the appropriate tag.

Comment: I am using C# language

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use [xsd.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx) for purposes like this. You'll need to add the appropriate Xml [serialization attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx) to the the C# class to get it, and [set the right flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3) on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. But xsd.exe could not help.

Solution:
Extract custom attributes of class member, loop every member and generate schema manually.

Thanks,
Vanita Arora